# Should I log a variable that is not normally distributed to be able to make categories for crosstabs?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, modeling, panel-data

I’m researching the correlation between democracy and the amount of foreign aid per capita received
in developing countries. My database contains panel data from the same population (N=121) in datasets with gaps of five years in between during the period 1991-2016. The measure for democracy is on a scale from 1-7. I have already carried out a Spearman correlation analysis from which I got a significant negative correlation, both for all the observations together and when analyzing each year individually (except for 2016).

To check the robustness of these results, I want to do a new test with crosstabs where I divide the values for aid per capita into three categories: low, medium and high. The problem is that aid per capita is not at all normally distributed. Low values are clearly over-represented and high values are very rare. The median for aid per capita for all observations is 42,4, while the highest value is 3731,7. The high category would contain only a few observations while the low category would have most of all the observations. This pattern repeats itself regardless of which year I look at.

My question is if I can and should log aid per capita so the variable becomes more normally distributed and it is easier to create and compare categories? If I do this, should I also use the logged variable for my correlation analysis?

Comment: Why not choose category boundaries so you get equal numbers in each?

Comment: Thank you! I did this.